# How to merge changes from Github to TFS

Tags: github, tfs

So I'm working semi-remotely on a project for a company with a small team. We have only a single VPN-enabled laptop to access their TFS which remains in a single secure office. We want to use Github to collaborate and get all our work onto the company Laptop, and then transfer that work to the company's TFS.

However I can't find a way to merge changes from the Github repo on the laptop to the TFS repo on the laptop without just brute-force ctrl-c/ctrl-v the directory which does not seem like the ideal solution.

Here is the file situation on the laptop with an arrow indicating the desired change transfer

[image: Here is the file situation on the laptop with an arrow indicating the desired change transfer]

Is there any clean way to do this?

Comment: Is git initialized on the TFS? The window to the left

Comment: @miqdadamirali no, having git initialized in the TFS repo caused sync issues; we couldn't get Visual Studio couldn't manage two source control connections for the same project simultaneously.

Comment: Why don't you add TFS and GitHub as two separate remotes and just use Git to do the pull/merge/push workflow?

Answer (score 1):

You can merge changes from github to TFS repo by below steps:

1. Move files into subfolder in local github repo

   Assume `DEV` is the subfolder for TFS git repo root directory, you can create the same folder `DEV` in github repo, and move files in the subfolder:

   ```
   # In local github repo
   mkdir DEV
   mv * DEV
   git add . 
   git commit -m 'move files into DEV folder'
   ```
2. Add local github repo as a remote for local TFS repo

   Assume the local github repo in C:\GitHub\My_Workflow_Dashboard,then you can add the local repo as the remote for your local TFS git repo:

   ```
   git remote add github C:/GitHub/My_Workflow_Dashboard -f
   ```
3. Merge changes from github into TFS repo

   Then you can merge the changes from github (such as master branch) to TFS by below commands:

   ```
   git merge github/master --allow-unrelated-histories
   git push
   ```

   Or you can add `-X theirs` option (`git merge github/master --allow-unrelated-histories -X theirs`) to auto resolve merge conflicts by keeping the version from github repo.